Question about constructing $\otimes_{i=1}^n X_i$
I am reading Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces, by Raymond Ryan. I have a pretty basic question: In Exercise 1.3 we establish that $X \otimes (Y \otimes Z) \cong (X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$, for vector spaces $X,Y$ and $Z$ hence we can unambiguously define the space $X \otimes Y \otimes Z$. However, previously he only constructed the tensor product $X\otimes Y$ for two vector spaces $X$ and $Y$. To construct $(X \otimes Y) \otimes Z$, for example, I assume we can just use the construction for two vector spaces again, since $X \otimes Y$ is a new vector space. Then we can do the same for $(X\otimes Y \otimes Z)\otimes W$, for another vector space $W$. By induction, this then extends to $\otimes_{i=1}^n X_i$ for vector spaces $X_i, i = 1 ,\ldots,n, n \in \mathbb{N}$, I suppose. It seems pretty straightforward, unless I am missing something?

Yes, sure. But you can also directly define the tensor product $\bigotimes_{i \in I} V_i$ of any family of vector spaces $(V_i)_{i \in I}$ by the universal property* and construct it as the free vector space on $\prod_{i \in I} V_i$ modulo the multilinear relations, so for example
$$(v_1 + v'_1,v_2,\dotsc) = (v_1,v_2,\dotsc) + (v'_1,v_2,\dotsc)$$
when $I = \mathbb{N}$ etc. There is no need to restrict to $\# I = 2$ first.
*The universal property states that there is a natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(\bigotimes_{i \in I} V_i,W) \cong \mathrm{Mult}((V_i)_{i \in I}, W)$, where the latter is the set of multilinear maps.
